# Jquery sorting table rows in multiple ways

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort a table based on several criteria at once.

The list should be sorted alphabetically A -> Z ignoring case.

Then if a row has a `data-order` assigned it should be recorded so they are placed in priority order 1 -> 49

Any entry with no data-order set, or with an data-order over 49 should be added below the list keeping the A-Z rule.

```
<tr id='1' data-order=''><td>Albert</td></tr>
<tr id='2' data-order='50'><td>Brian</td></tr>
<tr id='3' data-order='1'><td>Charles</td></tr>
<tr id='4' data-order=''><td>Bank</td></tr>
<tr id='5' data-order='1'><td>Alan</td></tr>
```

I would expect this to appear on screen as:

```
Alan
Charles
Albert
Bank
Brian
```

So the above list is worked out as:

Alan / Charles both have a data-order of 1, so they appear first in alphabetical order.

Albert / Bank / Brian appear next and are treated the same as some have no data-order and Brian is 50.
They are shown in alphabetical order.

So far I've got the A -> ordering sorted:

```
var $table=$('#FRM');
rows = $table.find('tbody').find('tr');
sortedRows = rows.sort( function (a, b) {
if ( $(a) >  $(b) )  {
    return 1;
}

if ( $(a) <  $(b) )  {
    return -1;
}
return 0;
})
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here.  Has anyone any ideas how to do this ?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

The following seems to do what I want..

```
var $table=$('#FRM');
    rows = $table.find('tbody').find('tr');
    sortedRows = rows.sort( function (a, b) {
        
    if ( a.dataset.order == '') a.dataset.order = 50
    if ( b.dataset.order == '') b.dataset.order = 50
        
    if ( a.dataset.order  > b.dataset.order )  return 1;
    if ( a.dataset.order  < b.dataset.order )  return -1;   
        
    if ( $(a) > $(b) )  return 1;
    if ( $(a) < $(b) )  return -1;

})
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The following seems to not do what you want.

Comment: @VXp - Can you explain please ?

Comment: I don't think you've tested it.